# SQL Error mismatched input 'IN' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

Tags: sql

I am trying to select out rows with certain values in a column.

The error I am getting is "mismatched input 'IN' expecting {, ';'}"

The code I am using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM drug_exposure
WHERE drug_concept_id IN (1111,1112,95768,1145689)
OR drug_source_concept_id IN (1111,1112,95768,1145689)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please precise your dbms

Comment: can you share the schema for `drug_exposure`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and then discovered that I had a mix of text and numbers in my list and had not wrapped them in quote marks.  That solved it for me.